# need help script

Tags: shell

I am trying to solve this problem for a long time.Please show me the light.

file1.txt

```
Alya Grant
cat
dog

Ava
dog
tiger
snake

Samia
bus
train
car
plane
```

I need output result is like this.

```
Alya Grant
cat
dog
Alya Grant=2

Ava
dog
tiger
snake
Ava=3

Samia
bus
train
car
plane
Samia=4
```

(or) like this

```
Alya Grant=2
Ava=3
Samia=4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is not working exactly?

Comment: As you have tried for a long time, you should show your failed attempts. Maybe we can help to fix/improve your code. I would use `awk` to implement this.

Comment: Please put some effort into giving your question an informative title - *describing* your problem is the first step to solving it

Comment: Will each group be separated by an empty line?  Will each name begin with a capital letter where each animal/object will begin with a lowercase?  Humans can easily recognize names in a group of words but programs can't do so as easily, it would be better to have other criteria to go by.

Comment: -1 for the imaginative title and the "show me the light".

Comment: Wow. I haven't seen a -10 on this site for a very very long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `/path/to/input-file` contains the list you mentioned in your post, we could use:

```
awk 'BEG{name="";count=0}{if ($0 == "") { print name "=" count; name = ""; count=0; } else { if (name == "") { name = $0; } else {count = count + 1} }}END{print name "=" count;}' /path/to/input-file
Alya Grant=2
Ava=3
Samia=4
```

Comment: I am clear now.Thanks a lot.I need to learn more 'awk' command.Thanks for the light.Please suggest me book or website to learn shell the easy way.

Answer (score 0):

With awk, use a sequence of blank lines as the *record separator* and newline as the *field separator*. Then the output is just the first field and the number of fields minus 1.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = "\n"; RS = ""; OFS = "="}
    { print $1, NF - 1 }
' file1.txt
```